# Notice: Undefined index: path in Drupal\Core\Routing\

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-8

I made a module in Drupal 8 and after i add the routing i got a notice in log messages telling:

> Notice: Undefined index: path in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (line 172 of /home/...

my module routing.yml looks like this:

```
---
mymodule.mypage:
  path: /mypage
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyPageController::customPage
    _title: My custom page
requirements:
  _role: anonymous
```

Accesing the page i got this message:

> Access denied
>   You are not authorized to access this page.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wrong indentation to me. And maybe don't check for a role but the `access content` permission.

```
mymodule.mypage:
  path: '/mypage'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyPageController::customPage'
    _title: 'My custom page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```